# Executar comandos em uma string em C++

Tags: c++, c++11, parser

Tenho comandos em uma *string* algo como:

```
string comm = "int x; cout << \"Digite um número\"; cin << x;";
```

Minha ideia é executar os comandos que estão nessa *string*, tendo o resultado como se eu tivesse digitado:

```
int x
cout << "Digite um número";
cin << x;
```

Existe algum comando que faça isso?

Eu pensei em fazer utilizando em leitor que identifica padrões e executa funções, mas isso ficaria muito complicado, além do que, não sei como faria para criar as variáveis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma geral não tem não, você tem que criar praticamente um compilador que faça isso por você. Claro que pode usar o que tem pronto como base pra adaptar.

Óbvio que se você restringir o que pode usar, pode ficar mais fácil fazer algo mais simples que um compilador completo, até porque um compilador de C++ é muito complicado, C++ é considerada a linguagem *mainstream* mais complicada que existe de interpretar.

Se acha *pattern matching* complicado, então esquece, porque é muito mais complicado que isso.

Comment: Eu pensei em gravar um arquivo .cpp com o conteúdo da string e mandar o compilador executar, isso é possível?

Comment: É, claro, claro que na prática isso não tem utilidade desta forma simples assim, e tem enormes desvantagens, então isso fica meio no campo teórico.

Comment: E o que daria certo? Como eu disse na pergunta, o maior problema é declarar variáveis.

Comment: Não, esse não é o maior problema, o que você está querendo saber é um vírgula em um livro inteiro, desiste dessa ideia.